# OSGi two dependency chains - cannot resolve dependencies

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, bndtools, amdatu

We're using OSGi for a rest application using bdntools and eclipse. We've deployed the application and everything is working OK.
The run descriptor we were using was OK, but we've copied the run requirements to a new run descriptor and now we are unable to resolve the dependencies, caused by the following error:

```
Uses constraint violation. 
Unable to resolve resource org.apache.felix.http.whiteboard [org.apache.felix.http.whiteboard ver=2.2.0]
because it is exposed to package 'javax.servlet' from resources
org.amdatu.multitenant.org.apache.felix.http.jetty [org.amdatu.multitenant.org.apache.felix.http.jetty ver=1.0.0]
and org.apache.felix.http.jetty [org.apache.felix.http.jetty ver=2.2.0] via two dependency chains.
```

We're having this problem more often, usually it is solved by creating a new run descriptor, but not this time..

Is this a bug in bndtools or are we doing something wrong? We also have the impression it might have something to do with multiple repositories.

**Edit:**
Here is the run descriptor and are the manifests of the bundles.

**Run descriptor:**

```
-runfw: org.apache.felix.framework;version='[4,5)'
-runee: JavaSE-1.7
-runsystemcapabilities: ${native_capability}

-resolve.effective: active

-runrequires: osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.apache.felix.gogo.shell)',\
osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.apache.felix.gogo.command)',\
osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.apache.felix.http.jetty)',\
osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.apache.felix.http.whiteboard)'
```

**Manifest org.apache.felix.http.jetty:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: org.apache.felix.http.api;uses:="javax.servlet,org.osg
i.service.http";version="2.0.4",org.osgi.service.http;uses:="javax.se
rvlet.http,javax.servlet";version="1.2",javax.servlet.resources;versi
on="2.5",javax.servlet;version="2.5",javax.servlet.jsp.resources;vers
ion="2.5",javax.servlet.http;uses:="javax.servlet";version="2.5"
Built-By: fmeschbe
Tool: Bnd-0.0.357
Bundle-Name: Apache Felix Http Jetty
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Bundle-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
DynamicImport-Package: org.osgi.service.cm;version=1.2
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_13
Bundle-Version: 2.2.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1296053619491
Bundle-Activator: org.apache.felix.http.jetty.internal.JettyActivator
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
Bundle-Description: Apache Felix is an OSGi implementation.
Bundle-DocURL: http://www.apache.org/
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.felix.http.jetty
Import-Package: javax.net.ssl;resolution:=optional,javax.security.cert
;resolution:=optional,javax.servlet;resolution:=optional;version="2.5
",javax.servlet.http;resolution:=optional;version="2.5",javax.servlet
.jsp.resources;resolution:=optional;version="2.5",javax.servlet.resou
rces;resolution:=optional;version="2.5",javax.xml.parsers;resolution:
=optional,org.apache.felix.http.api;resolution:=optional;version="2.0
",org.osgi.framework;resolution:=optional;version="1.3",org.osgi.serv
ice.http;resolution:=optional;version="1.2",org.osgi.service.log;reso
lution:=optional;version="1.3",org.osgi.util.tracker;resolution:=opti
onal;version="1.3",org.slf4j;resolution:=optional,org.xml.sax;resolut
ion:=optional,org.xml.sax.helpers;resolution:=optional
```

**Manifest org.amdatu.multitenant.org.apache.felix.http.jetty:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1338812262683
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_32
Built-By: ?
Bundle-Activator: org.amdatu.tenant.adapter.MultiTenantBundleActivator
Bundle-License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Amdatu Web - Multi-Tenant HttpService
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.amdatu.multitenant.org.apache.felix.http.jetty
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Embed-Dependency: *;scope=compile;inline=true
Embed-Transitive: false
Export-Package: org.apache.felix.http.api;uses:="javax.servlet,org.osgi.
service.http";version="2.0.4",org.osgi.service.http;uses:="javax.servle
t.http,javax.servlet";version="1.2",javax.servlet.resources;version="2.
5",javax.servlet;version="2.5",javax.servlet.jsp.resources;version="2.5
",javax.servlet.http;uses:="javax.servlet";version="2.5"
Import-Package: javax.net.ssl;resolution:=optional,javax.security.cert;r
esolution:=optional,javax.servlet;resolution:=optional;version="2.5",ja
vax.servlet.http;resolution:=optional;uses:="javax.servlet";version="2.
5",javax.servlet.jsp.resources;resolution:=optional;version="2.5",javax
.servlet.resources;resolution:=optional;version="2.5",javax.xml.parsers
;resolution:=optional,org.amdatu.tenant;version="[1.0,2)",org.amdatu.te
nant.adapter;version="[1.0,2)",org.apache.felix.http.api;resolution:=op
tional;uses:="javax.servlet,org.osgi.service.http";version="2.0",org.os
gi.framework;resolution:=optional;version="1.3",org.osgi.service.cm;res
olution:=optional;version="1.2",org.osgi.service.http;resolution:=optio
nal;uses:="javax.servlet.http,javax.servlet";version="1.2",org.osgi.ser
vice.log;resolution:=optional;version="1.3",org.osgi.util.tracker;resol
ution:=optional;version="1.3",org.slf4j;resolution:=optional,org.xml.sa
x;resolution:=optional,org.xml.sax.helpers;resolution:=optional
Tool: Bnd-1.50.0
X-MultiTenant-Binding: PLATFORM
X-MultiTenant-Bundle-Activator: org.apache.felix.http.jetty.internal.Jet
tyActivator
X-MultiTenant-Scope: (&(objectClass=org.osgi.service.log.LogService)(|(o
rg.amdatu.tenant.pid=%TENANTPID%)(!(org.amdatu.tenant.pid=*))))
X-MultiTenant-Version: 1
```

**Whiteboard manifest:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1386080857007
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_40
Built-By: jawi
Bundle-Activator: org.apache.felix.http.whiteboard.internal.WhiteboardAc
 tivator
Bundle-Description: Apache Felix is an OSGi implementation.
Bundle-DocURL: http://www.apache.org/
Bundle-License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Apache Felix Http Whiteboard
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.felix.http.whiteboard
Bundle-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Bundle-Version: 2.2.2
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Embed-Dependency: org.apache.felix.http.base;inline=org/apache/felix/htt
 p/base/internal/AbstractActivator*.class|org/apache/felix/http/base/int
 ernal/logger/*
Export-Package: org.apache.felix.http.whiteboard;version="1.0"
Implementation-Title: Apache Felix Http Whiteboard
Implementation-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Vendor-Id: org.apache.felix
Implementation-Version: 2.2.2
Import-Package: javax.servlet,javax.servlet.http,org.apache.felix.http.a
 pi;version="[2.0,3)",org.osgi.framework;version="[1.5,2)",org.osgi.serv
 ice.http;version="[1.2,2)",org.osgi.service.log;version="[1.3,2)",org.o
 sgi.util.tracker;version="[1.4,2)"
Specification-Title: Apache Felix Http Whiteboard
Specification-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Specification-Version: 2.2.2
Tool: Bnd-1.50.0
```

Comment: Could you at least post the manifests of the bundles that are involved? From your description it looks like you are deploying two "jetty" versions (one from the Amdatu project and one from Felix) and I think you only need one. So that might be one solution to your problem. For a better analysis of the uses constraint violation, more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there seems to be a bug (in my opinion) in the repositories.bnd. It seems that the amdatu release repository needs to be above dependencies and snapshots.. The following changes solved the bug:

```
-plugin:\
aQute.bnd.deployer.repository.LocalIndexedRepo; name=Release;      local=${workspace}/cnf/releaserepo;pretty=true,\
aQute.bnd.deployer.repository.LocalIndexedRepo; name=Local;        local=${workspace}/cnf/localrepo;pretty=true,\
    aQute.bnd.deployer.repository.FixedIndexedRepo; name=Bndtools Hub; locations=https://github.com/bndtools/bundle-hub/raw/master/index.xml.gz,\
    aQute.bnd.deployer.repository.FixedIndexedRepo; name=Amdatu Dependencies; locations=http://repository.amdatu.org/dependencies/index.xml.gz,\
    aQute.bnd.deployer.repository.FixedIndexedRepo; name=Amdatu Snapshots; locations=http://repository.amdatu.org/snapshot/index.xml.gz,\
    aQute.bnd.deployer.repository.FixedIndexedRepo; name=Amdatu Release; locations=http://repository.amdatu.org/release/index.xml.gz,\
    aQute.lib.deployer.FileRepo;                    name=Build;        location=${workspace}/cnf/buildrepo

-releaserepo: Release
```

.

```
-plugin:\
    aQute.bnd.deployer.repository.LocalIndexedRepo; name=Release;      local=${workspace}/cnf/releaserepo;pretty=true,\
    aQute.bnd.deployer.repository.LocalIndexedRepo; name=Local;        local=${workspace}/cnf/localrepo;pretty=true,\
    aQute.bnd.deployer.repository.FixedIndexedRepo; name=Bndtools Hub; locations=https://github.com/bndtools/bundle-hub/raw/master/index.xml.gz,\
    aQute.bnd.deployer.repository.FixedIndexedRepo; name=Amdatu Release; locations=http://repository.amdatu.org/release/index.xml.gz,\
    aQute.bnd.deployer.repository.FixedIndexedRepo; name=Amdatu Dependencies; locations=http://repository.amdatu.org/dependencies/index.xml.gz,\
    aQute.bnd.deployer.repository.FixedIndexedRepo; name=Amdatu Snapshots; locations=http://repository.amdatu.org/snapshot/index.xml.gz,\
    aQute.lib.deployer.FileRepo;                    name=Build;        location=${workspace}/cnf/buildrepo

-releaserepo: Release
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is happening because the `javax.servlet` is available from resources
org.amdatu.multitenant.org.apache.felix.http.jetty org.amdatu.multitenant.org.apache.felix.http.jetty ver=1.0.0 and org.apache.felix.http.jetty org.apache.felix.http.jetty ver=2.2.0 so the module `org.apache.felix.http.whiteboard` does not know which `javax.servlet` to wire with. you could solve the problem by removing the duplication.

Comment: Seems straight forward, how do I do this?